# datatables collapsed rowsGroup + bootstrap. Сворачиваемые группировки в таблице

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Хочу сделать возможность сворачивания группировки в таблице используя bootstrap 3. То есть при клике на строчку, она сворачивает-разворачивает потомков.

[Вот что есть](http://jsfiddle.net/no_fx/eL1507kh/31/), но проблема в том, что в таблицу нельзя вставлять `<div>` как того [требует](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp) фреймворк bootstrap, поэтому сворачивается только первая строка.

Можно реализовать конечно [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46414643/jquery-datatables-rowgroup-collapse-expand) (оно работает), но хочется c bootstrap...

Comment: Если Вы хотите использовать bootstrap, то надо использовать верстку как в документации. А если у Вас версткая другая, то тогда надо уже делать свои велосипеды.

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв